# button which open array links on same page in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to open webpage through array link data while pressing the button on remaining same page, I've tried many time houres and houres work but my code did not work. I try to detect where is fault but not understand , how to solve it. Please help.

This is code of open webpage by array link data while pressing button or pagination.

```
             <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php


$data=array("www.google.com","www.google.com/1","www.google.com/2");


foreach ($data[0] as $url) {

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$code=curl_exec($ch);


function openpage() {

global $code;
echo $code;

}

curl_close($ch);

}

?>

<button onclick= openpage();>open NEXT array PAGE</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what issues are you facing? is the curl even running? what is the error?

Comment: you do understand your culr is just resetting every time you run the for loop, right?

Comment: button did not getting any array data, and also did not opening link when click on it.

Comment: @mashtan error: Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given on line 17

Comment: i checked this code on local host, please anyone help

Answer (score 0):

**PHP** is executed on the server and the **javascript** is executed on the browser.

It looks like you are trying to call a PHP function from javascript.  You can only call a javascript function in the **onclick** event.  And you have to populate the function call with a parameter being the page you want to go to.

Comment: i cannot know, how to do it

Comment: @moazam you cant do it with php. php is server side language, not client side. you need to use html or js to do this. I have provided an answer for you, but I need to be honest with you. if you do not have this basic level of knowledge, perhaps you should not be attempting to write independent code at this level just yet. Learn from tutorials and take your time.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned ( did not opening link when click on it.). Buttons do not open links. Anchor tags do. If you really need a button, you can use the btn class to make it look like one.What you are doing is you are trying to print the response you get from the curl. That is not opening a page. Curls do not open new tabs. it returns a response from that particular link.

```
<?php

$data=array("www.google.com","www.google.com/1","www.google.com/2");
foreach ($data[0] as $url) { 

?>
 <a href='$url' target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">Click to Open</a>

<?php } ?>
```